# htaccess redirection 301 in apache 2.4 not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, apache2.4

How to redirect directory http://www.example.com/contact/ to file http://www.example.com/contact-us.php

My htaccess file contents

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/contact/$ http://www.example.com/contact-us.php [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

> RewriteRule ^/contact/$ http://www.example.com/contact-us.php [L,R=301]

The ^/ will never match in RewriteRule in htaccess.  If this is in the document root, remove the first `/`.

When mod_rewrite is used in .htaccess, the URL-path that brought you to that htaccess file has been stripped off and you only match the relative/remaining path.